# Python: subprocess call with shell=False not working

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I am using Python script to invoke a Java virtual machine. The following command works:

```
subprocess.call(["./rvm"], shell=False)  # works
subprocess.call(["./rvm xyz"], shell=True) # works
```

But,

```
subprocess.call(["./rvm xyz"], shell=False) # not working
```

does not work. [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) advices to avoid `shell=True`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You need to split the commands  into separate strings:

```
subprocess.call(["./rvm", "xyz"], shell=False)
```

A string will work when `shell=True` but you need a list of args when `shell=False`

The [shlex](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shlex.html) module is useful more so for more complicated commands and dealing with input but good to learn about:

```
import shlex

cmd = "python  foo.py"
subprocess.call(shlex.split(cmd), shell=False)
```

[shlex tut](http://pymotw.com/2/shlex/)

Comment: This answer also solved my problem. Can you elaborate on why "A string will work when shell=True but you need a list of args when shell=False" is? I've heard `shell=True` is extremely dangerous when there is input so I'm trying to avoid it.

Comment: @Tommy,  generally shell=True is best avoided, it is not the end of the world if you use it if you are completely in control of what you are running but almost everything that you can do with shell=True you can do with shell=False. When you pass a list of args at least on unix the first arg is the command to execute and the rest are the args for that command, if you use shell=True you must pass the command exactly as you would if you were passing it to the shell,  example of what shell=True could allow https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments

Comment: i think it is a strange API to have the structure of one argument change (here the arg list or command) based on another boolean argument (whether Shell=True). This should be internally handled in subprocess so that the same argument is passed regardless of `shell`.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use `shell=True`, this is legit, otherwise it would have been removed from the standard library. The documentation doesn't say to avoid it, it [says](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

> Executing shell commands that incorporate unsanitized input from an untrusted source makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, a serious security flaw which can result in arbitrary command execution. For this reason, the use of `shell=True` is strongly discouraged in cases where **the command string is constructed from external input**.

But in your case you are not constructing the command from user input, your command is constant, so your code doesn't present the *shell injection* issue. You are in control of what the shell will execute, and if your code is not malicious per se, you are safe.

#### Example of shell injection

To explain why the shell injection is so bad, this is the example used in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments):

```
>>> from subprocess import call
>>> filename = input("What file would you like to display?\n")
What file would you like to display?
non_existent; rm -rf / #
>>> call("cat " + filename, shell=True) # Uh-oh. This will end badly...
```

#### Edit

With the additional information you have provided editing the question, stick to [Padraic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2141635/padraic-cunningham)'s answer. You should use `shell=True` only when necessary.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Enrico.bacis' answer, there are two ways to call programs.  With `shell=True`, give it a full command string.  With `shell=False`, give it a list.

If you do shell tricks like `*.jpg` or `2> /dev/null`, use `shell=True`; but in general I suggest `shell=False` -- it's more durable as Enrico said.

### source

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['/bin/echo', 'beer'], shell=False)
subprocess.check_call('/bin/echo beer', shell=True)
```

### output

```
beer
beer
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the filename directory, add the word `python` in front of it, provided that you've added python path to your environmental variables. If you're not sure, you can always rerun the python installer, once again, provided that you have a new version of python.

Here's what I mean:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('python "C:/Path/To/File/Here.py"')
```