# Running application script inside python

Tags: python-2.7

So, I have an external application which I put it in my */opt/app/bin/thisapp* directory. The application can be executed via command line and will give output to stdout. I add */opt/app/bin/* to my environment variable. Basically, I can call *thisapp* in my terminal and produce an output.

I am trying to call this application inside a python and capture its output inside python. This is my script (really simple):

```
from subprocess import call
call(["thisapp"])
```

It ressults in an error

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I already make sure to chmod 777 -R in the directory but still same. Then I am trying to call the absolute path of this app which is:

call(["/opt/app/bin/thisapp"])

This time, the error is:

```
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can anyone suggest what should I do? I am really new to python.

Comment: Are you really *really* sure that the full path to the program is `/opt/app/bin/thisapp`? What if you do `sudo chmod +x path/to/app` to make it executable?

Comment: I already make sure calling this via terminal. That's why it is weird and it is already executable.

Comment: What if you copy the program to your home folder and try to run it via python again? What if you do `import sys; sys.path.append("/opt/app/bin/")`? Does `which thisapp` in terminal show the full path you're specifying in python?

Comment: I copy the script to my python directory, same as my python script. In terminal I tried calling it via ./thisapp and it is success. Via python, I call it:

   call(["./thisapp"])

It is still not working. The error is no such file or directory. I tried the import sys still not working.

Comment: I add shell=TRUE and it is working!

Comment: Ok, `shell=True` can be a security risk though - best to avoid it if you can. Check [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2tzljx/shelltrue_with_subprocess_methods/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465700/python-subprocess-call-with-shell-false-not-working). I think there's either still something wrong with your path environment variables (and therefore the path you're specifying isn't found) or maybe you're passing arguments to `thisapp` but haven't mentioned it.

Comment: Oh, I noticed that I used another parameter in my call earlier. I call the app call("thisapp param1"). So, should I split into : call(["thisapp","param1"])? If I have more than 2 params, should I call this : call(["thisapp","param1","param2"])?

Comment: There are parameters?! You should mention that! You write `call(["/opt/app/bin/thisapp"])` in your question and but now you mention parameters? Why didn't you add that to the question?

Comment: My bad, because when I check the existence of file I use parameter and I just copy and paste to the script. So, I don't realize parameter si the problem.

Comment: `subprocess.call(["/opt/bin/app/thisapp", "param1", "param2", "param ..."])`

Comment: Ok, it is working now and great. Already start processing the output. Thank you very much. Just first day writing Python script.

Comment: Cool, you're welcome!