# Why does this Python subprocess command only work when shell=True on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, imagemagick, subprocess

I have a python script that involves multiple `subprocess.call` commands. I wrote the script on a Mac, and it runs perfectly. I just tried running it on Windows and I am baffled by an error.

The following command to call ImageMagick returns "exit status 4":

```
file1 = "D:/Temp/OCR_test/sample/images/crops/time_0011.png"
subprocess.call(['convert', file1, '-resize', '200%', file1])
```

Changing the command to the following works:

```
subprocess.call(['convert', file1, '-resize', '200%', file1], shell=True)
```

I'm a little wary of using `shell=True` because of the warnings in the documentation.
I also need the command to work on both Mac and Windows, and I am confused as to why it wouldn't work on Windows (I checked and the command does work using Windows CMD).

Interestingly, the following line worked earlier in the script (where `file`, `lat_crop1`, and `croplat` are defined variables):

```
subprocess.call(['ffmpeg', '-loglevel', 'panic', '-i', file, '-vf', lat_crop1, '-n', croplat])
```

I read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465700/python-subprocess-call-with-shell-false-not-working) and tried all the suggestions (shlex, variations of my command, etc...), but I still get the same result.

Anyone have any idea how I could modify that line so it can work without `shell=True`?

Also, what does "exit status 4" mean? I Googled and read so much documentation but found nothing about it.

**EDIT:** Based on the information provided in the answer, I changed to the command that was not working to `subprocess.call(['mogrify', file1, '-resize', '200%', file1])` and that runs successfully in Python on Windows. Luckily ImageMagick provides `mogrify` as an alternative to `convert`.

Comment: What is the `convert` command? ImageMagick?

Comment: Yes, it's ImageMagick I forgot to mention that. It does work in command line.

Comment: can you type `where convert` from the command line?

Comment: Didn't know about that command! It returns `C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-6.9.2-Q16-HDRI\convert.exe` and `C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe`  I see how that could create problems now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you're calling `C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe` (NTFS/FAT partition converter) instead of imagemagick.

When `shell=True`, the path finds the `convert.bat` or `convert.cmd` script from imagemagick, but without it, the path can only find the `.exe` file, which is a completely different program, and you get error 4: invalid parameter.

In that particular case, it doesn't work even with an executable, because the "wrong" `convert` is located in a system path. `shell=False` only searches in system paths ([python subprocess Popen environment PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658622/python-subprocess-popen-environment-path)). So that's bad luck that a program named `convert` is located in the system path.

Try to explicitly add `.bat` extension like this:

```
subprocess.call(['convert.bat', file1, '-resize', '200%', file1])
```

To know which executables are likely to be run you can type:

```
where convert
```

in a command prompt.

In your case (an executable), that could be workarounded by passing the absolute path of the executable you want to run.

Another way would be to copy/rename ImageMagick `convert` to `imconvert`. Which program calls itself `convert` and doesn't expect conflicts anyway ?

Or in that case, it's legitimate to leave `shell=True`, with a nice comment explaining that Microsoft left a confusing (and seldom used `convert` program in a system path for us to trip into)

Solutions are not pretty, at least there are some.

Comment: [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682425) always searches system directories before `PATH` and tries appending ".EXE". The cmd shell, on the other hand, does its own search of `PATH`, and tries appending the extensions in `PATHEXT`,  and then it calls `CreateProcess` with the fully-qualified path of the file that it finds.

Comment: @eryksun: found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658622/python-subprocess-popen-environment-path. Your explanation is the best one. I'm editing.

Comment: That's really interesting and great to know about other `convert` programs. Adding the full path in the `subprocess` command worked. Thank you for the suggestion. Also changing the ImageMagick module to `imconvert` could be a good idea. I agree that it's weird they would use such a generic name.

Comment: I suggest they call it `dir` the next time :) most interesting question today by far. Just when I thought I knew windows very well...