# subprocess.Popen doesn't work with shell=False

Tags: python, shell, subprocess

I try to run simple script in windows in the same shell.
When I run

```
subprocess.call(["python.exe", "a.py"], shell=False)
```

It works fine.

But when I run

```
subprocess.Popen(["python.exe", "a.py"], shell=False)
```

It opens new shell and the shell=false has no affect.

a.py just print message to the screen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: subprocess call with shell=False not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465700/python-subprocess-call-with-shell-false-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

First calling `Popen` with `shell=False` doesn't mean that the underlying python won't try to open a window/console. It's just that the current python instance executes `python.exe` directly and not in a system shell (cmd or sh).

Second, `Popen` returns a handle on the process, and you have to perform a `wait()` on this handle for it to end properly or you could generate a defunct process (depending on the platform you're running on). I suggest that you try

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["python.exe", "a.py"], shell=False)
return_code = p.wait()
```

to wait for process termination and get return code.

Note that `Popen` is a very bad way to run processes in background. The best way would be to use a separate thread

```
import subprocess
import threading

def run_it():
    subprocess.call(["python.exe", "a.py"], shell=False)

t = threading.Thread(target=run_it)
t.start()
# do your stuff

# in the end
t.join()
```

Comment: But I don't want to wait until the process will finish.. this is the reason I use Popen and not call.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that it still waits until the thread finish... I want that my code will run, execute another process and exit. I don't want to wait for the process to finish.